# Binary Adder Validation Check

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am having errors currently with my Validation checking for my Binary Adder, only with checking its a 1 or a 0 though. I want it to check if the textbox's contain everything from 2 to 9 and from a to z.
My code is currently:

```
    Dim errorpass As Integer = 2
    Dim decnum As Integer = 2
    Dim errormsg As String = "ERROR:" + vbNewLine
    'Start of Error Checking
    'Checking if either textbox contains anything
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        errormsg += ("Please enter some form of input." + vbNewLine)
        errorpass = 1
        'Checking if either textbox are numbers
    ElseIf Not (IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Or IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text)) Then
        errormsg += ("Please enter a number." + vbNewLine)
        errorpass = 1
        'Checking if either textbox contains 1's or 0's
        For i = 2 To 9
            If TextBox1.Text.Contains(decnum) Or TextBox2.Text.Contains(decnum) Then
                errormsg += ("Please enter binary." + vbNewLine)
                errorpass = 1
            ElseIf Not TextBox1.Text.Contains("1" Or "0") Or TextBox2.Text.Contains("1" Or "0") Then
                errorpass = 1
                If decnum = 9 Then
                    decnum = 2
                Else
                    decnum += 1
                End If
            Else
                errorpass = 2
            End If
        Next

    End If
    'Processing the request
    If errorpass = 1 Then
        MsgBox(errormsg, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, Title:="ERROR PROCESSING YOUR REQUEST")
    ElseIf errorpass = 2 Then
        'Adder
        TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text, 2) + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text, 2), 2)
    End If
    errorpass = 2
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the basics of a pattern to try

```
    Dim num1 As Integer
    Dim num2 As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, num1) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, num2) Then
        If Not ((num1 = 0 OrElse num1 = 1) AndAlso (num2 = 0 OrElse num2 = 1)) Then
            'not 0 or 1
            Stop
        Else
            '0 or 1
            Stop
        End If
    Else
        'error input - not a number
        Stop
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things with your code... first, you have your For loop inside of the ElseIf that checks if the fields are numeric or not. Second, within your For loop you are evaluating decnum instead of your counter, i. Try this:

```
Dim errorpass As Integer = 2
Dim decnum As Integer = 2
Dim errormsg As String = "ERROR:" + vbNewLine
'Start of Error Checking
'Checking if either textbox contains anything
If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
    errormsg += ("Please enter some form of input." + vbNewLine)
    errorpass = 1
    'Checking if either textbox are numbers
ElseIf Not (IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Or IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text)) Then
    errormsg += ("Please enter a number." + vbNewLine)
    errorpass = 1
Else
    'Checking if either textbox contains 1's or 0's
    For i = 2 To 9
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains(i) Or TextBox2.Text.Contains(i) Then
            errormsg += ("Please enter binary." + vbNewLine)
            errorpass = 1
        End If
    Next

End If
'Processing the request
If errorpass = 1 Then
    MsgBox(errormsg, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, Title:="ERROR PROCESSING YOUR REQUEST")
ElseIf errorpass = 2 Then
    'Adder
    TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text, 2) + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text, 2), 2)
End If
errorpass = 2
```